# Passing Node.JS variable into phantom-node's 'onUrlChanged' event and back it out

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I need to do some checks with data I'm receiving in 'onUrlChanged' event of phantom-node:

```
else (res.statusCode === 200) {
    var sitepage = null;
    var phInstance = null;
    var urlS = options.url;
      phantom.create()
      .then(function(instance) {
        phInstance = instance;
        return instance.createPage();
      })
      .then(function(page) {
        sitepage = page;
        page.property('onUrlChanged', function(requestData, networkRequest){
          console.log(urlS);
        });
        console.log('URL OPTS: ', urlS);
        return page.open(urlS);
      })
      .then(function(status) {
        console.log('STATUS: ', status);
        return sitepage.property('content');
      })
      .then(function(content) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(urlS);
          sitepage.close();
          phInstance.exit();
          cb(redirects);
        }, 16000);

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        phInstance.exit();
      });
  }
```

I get urlS as undefined inside 'onUrlChanged' and get it with a value below the code.
Is it a way to use Node's variables inside phantom-node or maybe to forward phantom-node's variable to Node?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATED:
I solved the issue with passing a var. It was the mistake in official docs of phantom.

```
        page.property('onUrlChanged', function(requestData, networkRequest, outVar, a) {

        console.log(outVar);

        }, outObj, outObj);
```

Take a look that it uses last outObj var after callback but 3rd argument in the callback function.

So, how can I return the var back with changes? I think to do that with write and read to a file. But it looks like ugly option.